# PGP file decryption from Linux cmd line

Tags: linux, gnupg, decryption

How can I decrypt a `.pgp` file to `.txt` file using a key(.asc file) with the Linux command line.

Answer (score 18):

Import your private key:

> ```
> cat mykey.asc # should start with
> -----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
> ```

```
gpg --import mykey.asc
```

Check if it shows up:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

Decrypt a message:

```
gpg --output ./decrypted_msg.txt --decrypt ./encrypted_msg.txt
```

Comment: when I do the 'gpg --import filename.asc' it returns an error:  gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/mypath/.gnupg/gpg.conf'

Comment: if your user is named `mypath` the do a `chown mypath:mypath ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`

Comment: Looks like I do not have permissions.  Waiting on the NetAdm to provide those.